# Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, база-данных

В БД есть записи: id bigint и type jsonb.

Делаю запрос к БД, получаю строки, типа:

```
1234, {'a': [12, 54, 34], 'b': [23, 45]}
1235, {'a':[23], 'b':[25]}
1236, {'a':[54, 15, 33], 'b':[22, 11]}
```

Мне нужно узнать, есть ли число Х в массиве а, и если есть удалить это число.

```
sqlGetData = 'SELECT id, type FROM data WHERE own = :p_ownid'
sqlUpdateData = 'UPDATE data SET type = :p_type ::jsonb WHERE (own = :p_ownid AND id = :p_id)'

own_id = 1
x = 54
dbcon = Session()
dataBD = dbcon.execute(sqlGetData, {'p_ownid': own_id}).fetchall()

for data in dataBD:
   id = data.id
   newTypeA = [i for i in data.type['a'] if i != x]
   dataNew = {'a': newTypeA, 'b': data.type['b']}
   if data.type['a'].count(x) > 0 :
       dbcon.execute(sqlUpdateData, {'p_ownid': own_id, 'p_id': id, 'p_type': json.dumps(dataNew)})
```

Во время выполнения данного запроса получаю ошибку:

> ```
> "error": "'int' object is not subscriptable"
> ```

Python ссылается на то, что `data.type['a']` у меня не массив из чисел, а просто число, то там ведь `[12, 54, 34]`???

Делаю проверку типа переменной `type(data.type['a'])`, получаю class `'list'`.

Comment: В data.type у вас int, попробуйте вывести `print(data.type)`. Кст, добавьте полную трассу стека ошибки

Comment: print(data.type) выдает {'a': [12, 54, 34], 'b': [23, 45]} вроде все нормально, но вот ошибка вылетает :( второй день воюю. Трассу стека ошибки не вижу, т.к. запускаю из под фласка, а он не логирует эти ошибки, кроме как ловлю Exception в виде "error": "'int' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 0):

Если попробовать просто в питоновском файле то всё работает.

```
x = 54

typel = {'a': [12, 54, 34], 'b': [23, 45]}
newTypeA = [i for i in typel['a'] if i != x]
dataNew = {'a': newTypeA, 'b': type1['b']}
if typel['a'].count(x) > 0 :
    print('no')
```

Может из БД приходит другой тип данных?

Comment: Просто в питоне все нормально, работает без ошибок. А вот во фласке из базы что-то тянет и вылетает exception

Comment: @IlyaRU разобрались в чем дело?